# warnCommentChanges always being triggered on update

Tags: comments, admin

I am developing a course using WPLMS and have an annoying problem with one of the WPLMS custom page types (units).  Here is a link to a thread I posted on the WPLMS support forums, but they can't reproduce the problem:

http://vibethemes.com/documentation/wplms/forums/topic/stop-annoying-unit-update-prompts/#post-86495

Basically every time I click Update when editing a unit I get the message "Are you sure you want to do this?  The comment changes you made will be lost."  It is displayed even if I don't make any changes to the page prior to clicking the Update button.  The message is not displayed for "regular" WP pages or other custom WPLMS page types (e.g. Modules).

The message is also displayed if I click the "Add Comment" button on the admin page.  After I clear the popup the comment textarea is not displayed as it is on regular pages.

The popup text is defined in script-loader.php and it seems like this message will be displayed when the warnCommentChanges flag is set.  But I'm not sure how or why the flag is set.  Does anyone know what the problem might be?  I can't think of any changes I made to the theme that might be causing this issue.